# Rock Paper Scissors game with wrong results

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a rock, paper scissors game form application and the code passes, however i can't seem to get it to work as it should. the user will type either paper, scissors or rock, then the computer shall choose 1-3, and 1 is rock, 2 is paper, 3 is scissors. you will win, lose or it will be a tie. sometimes no Printing comes, and otherwise it said you won, however you really lost. Forgive me if the code is hard to understand. I am a beginner.

```
string userAnswer = textBox1.Text;
Random r1 = new Random();
int b = 3;
string comrock = "The computer chose rock!";
string compaper = "The computer chose paper!";
string comscissors = "The computer chose scissors!";
int computerChoice = r1.Next(b);
if (computerChoice == 1)
{
    label4.Text = comrock;
}
else if (computerChoice == 2)
{
    label4.Text = compaper;
}
else if (computerChoice == 3)
{
    label4.Text = comscissors;
}
else
{
    while (computerChoice == 0)
    {
        computerChoice = r1.Next(b);

        if (computerChoice == 1)
        {
            label4.Text = comrock;
        }
        else if (computerChoice == 2)
        {
            label4.Text = compaper;
        }
        else if (computerChoice == 3)
        {
            label4.Text = comscissors;
        }
    }

        if (userAnswer == "rock") ;
        {
            if (computerChoice == 2) ;
            {
                label3.Text = "You lost....";
            }
        }
        if (userAnswer == "paper") ;
        {
            if (computerChoice == 1) ;
            {
                label3.Text = "You Won!";
            }
        }
        if (userAnswer == "rock") ;
        {
            if (computerChoice == 1) ;
            {
                label3.Text = "It's a tie!";
            }
        }
        if (userAnswer == "rock") ;
        {
            if (computerChoice == 3) ;
            {
                label3.Text = "You lost....";
            }
        }
    if (userAnswer == "paper");
    {
        if (computerChoice == 2) ;
        {
            label3.Text = "It's a tie!";
        }
    }
    if (userAnswer == "paper");
    {
        if (computerChoice == 3) ;
        {
            label3.Text = "You lost....";
        }
    }
    if (userAnswer == "scissors");
    {
        if (computerChoice == 2) ;
        {
            label3.Text = "You won!";
        }
    }
    if (userAnswer == "scissors");
    {
        if (computerChoice == 3) ;
        {
            label3.Text = "It's a tie!";
        }
    }
    if (userAnswer == "scissors");
    {
        if (computerChoice == 2) ;
        {
            label3.Text = "You won!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is about the least object-oriented C# one can imagine. Plus, the intermingling of RPS logic with UI logic is fine for a beginner hobbyist setting, but not good for maintenance or a team setting beyond that.

Comment: I don't want to think of your code if it were played with -say- 10 different *things*

Comment: i allready answered this quetion at all here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965901/how-to-display-results-of-rock-paper-scissors-game/38966414#38966414

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've misunderstood how `Next()` is working.  In your case, you're essentially calling it like so:

```
int computerChoice = r1.Next(3);
```

If you take a look at the intellisense for this, you'll see that it says:

> Returns a nonnegative random number less than the specified maximum.

In this case, you're setting the maximum to be `3`, so it will only ever return the values `0`, `1` or `2`.  That means this:

```
else if (computerChoice == 3)
```

will never be hit.  I assume this is also why you're using your `while` loop again, to try and correct the problem, but it's going to do the same thing of not allowing the computer to select `scissors`.

If you still want to constrain the valid values for `rock`, `paper` and `scissors` to be `1`, `2` and `3`, respectively, you simply need to add `1` to the result of calling `Next()`:

```
int computerChoice = r1.Next(b) + 1;
```

Now that you have your values in the proper range, you don't need your `while` loop at all.  So your `computerChoice` code can be simplified to:

```
if (computerChoice == 1)
{
    label4.Text = comrock;
}
else if (computerChoice == 2)
{
    label4.Text = compaper;
}
else if (computerChoice == 3)
{
    label4.Text = comscissors;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if i put in paper or scissors or rock, it Always says i lost.

Comment: @user3185801 Your logic for testing winning conditions isn't right at the moment.  As you're learning, I'd rather push you in the right direction instead of just giving you the code outright.  Right now, you're repeatedly checking if the user has chosen `rock`, `paper` or `scissors`.  A better way would be to only test for each one once.  For example, `if (userAnswer == "rock") { // check all winning conditions for rock } else if (userAnswer == "paper") { // do the same again }` and so on.

Comment: @user3185801 Once you have that working, think about how you can simplify your code further.  Ask yourself what logical conditions are being repeated and see what you can do about them.

Answer (score 0):

The value you set in `Random` has an exclusive upper-bound. That means that when you specify `r1.Next(3);`, you'll either get a 0, 1 or 2.

I haven't checked the rest of your code, but try changing the upper-limit you're passing to `r1.Next()`:

```
int b = 4;

...

int computerChoice = r1.Next(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Grant Winney mentioned, you will never get `computerChoice` to be 3 because `Next(x)` returns

> A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to zero, and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values ordinarily includes zero but not maxValue. However, if maxValue equals zero, maxValue is returned.

Second, don't make it return 0. Then you won't have to do that while loop. User `Next(1, 4)` to get only numbers {1, 2, 3}.

Then, convert user input to a number as well and compare numbers

```
if (userChoice == computerChoice)
{
    // tie
    return;
}
// other comparing
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just completed a short test project for a rock paper scissors game using C#/WebApi and with the front end in AngularJS.  It's not meant to be a full app just a proof of concept, but you may want to check out the source to see how I have structured the code in an more OOP way.  Tests in Specflow and Nunit are also included.

The source is on github => https://github.com/swin66/RockPaperScissors

And you can try the app => http://rockpaperscissors.azurewebsites.net