# How to display results of rock paper scissors game

Tags: c#

I am working on a rock paper scissors console application. I can get the game to run correctly, and display the winner of the individual game. I am unable to get all of the results to display at the end. At the end of the game, it should display the results of all of the games, and it should stop when someone wins enough games. The application currently closes after the last game is played and i cannot figure out why. This is the code i have, there are 3 different classes.

Class 1

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game rps = new Game();
            rps.printHeader();
            rps.userSettings();
            rps.gameStart();
        }
    }
}
```

Class 2

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class GameDetails
        {
            public string Name;
            public int game;
            public string Result;

        public GameDetails()
        {
            Name = "unknown";
            game = 0;
        }

        public GameDetails(string winner)
        {
            Result = winner;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally Class 3

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Game
    {
        string name;
        string winner;
        int numPlays;
        int game;
        GameDetails[] gameArray;



        public int NumGames
        {
            get
            {
                return numPlays;
            }
            set
            {
                numPlays = value;
            }

        }

        public string Winner
        {
            get
            {
                return winner;
            }
            set
            {
                winner = value;
            }
        }

        public void printHeader()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to rock, paper, scissors");
            this.userSettings();
        }

        private void InitializeArrays()
        {
            gameArray = new GameDetails[game];
            for (int game = 0; game < numPlays; game++)
            {
                gameArray[game] = new GameDetails();
            }

        }

        public void userSettings()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("How many games would you like to play?: ");
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numPlays);
            while (numPlays < 10 && numPlays % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nNumber is not odd try again.");
                Console.WriteLine("How many games would you like to play?: ");
                Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numPlays);
            }

        }


        public void gameStart()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            for (game = 1; game <= numPlays; game++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
                string userSelection = Console.ReadLine();


                int computerSelection = r.Next(4);


                if (computerSelection == 1)
                {
                    if (userSelection == "rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Rock\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("Game [{0}] is a tie", game);
                    }
                    else if (userSelection == "paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Paper\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("Game[{0}] is a tie", game);
                    }
                    else if (userSelection == "scissors")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Scissors\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("Game [{0}] is a tie", game);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You must choose either rock, paper or scissors");
                    }

                }

                else if (computerSelection == 2)
                {
                    if (userSelection == "rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Paper\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("You lose game [{0}], papaer beats rock", game);

                    }
                    else if (userSelection == "paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Scissors\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("You lose game [{0}], scissors beats paper", game);

                    }
                    else if (userSelection == "scissors")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Rock\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("You lose game [{0}], Rock beats scissors", game);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You must choose either rock, paper or scissors");
                    }

                }


                else if (computerSelection == 3)
                {
                    if (userSelection == "rock")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose scissors");
                        Console.WriteLine("You win game [{0}], rock beats scissors", game);

                    }
                    else if (userSelection == "paper")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose rock");
                        Console.WriteLine("You win game [{0}],paper beats rock", game);

                    }
                    else if (userSelection == "scissors")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The computer chose paper");
                        Console.WriteLine("You win game [{0}], scissors beats paper!", game);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You must choose either rock, paper or scissors");

                    }

                    winner = Console.ReadLine();

                }


            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            int arrayIndex = game - 1;
            gameArray[arrayIndex].Result = winner;

            string outputString = game + "\n";

            for (int game = 1; game < numPlays; game++)
            {
                int index = game - 1;
                outputString += "Game " + game + ":" + gameArray[index].Result + "\n";
                }

                return outputString;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You should learn about the debugger - try setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code.

Comment: A question/ hint: How/ where do you print your results? Your main has gamestart.... then what?

Comment: @kurakura88 you make a good point. I need to adjust my main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey My Friend i will help at all. But if you Fallow the Comment of @Blorgbeard you won´t need this (Really is an appreciate comment, fallow it).

First You have an error in the class 1

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game rps = new Game();
        rps.printHeader();
        rps.userSettings();
        rps.gameStart();
    }
}
```

Delete this line "rps.userSettings();" because you allready have this in printHeader() procedure.

The Next Error i catched using "the debugger - try setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code" :)  was in this line in the Class 3

```
    int computerSelection = r.Next(4);
```

Change it for:

```
    int computerSelection = r.Next(1,3);
```

If you read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx you will know why is wrong :)

Now the last error i catched and is the reazon because you get close the console, just add this line to all this sentences (Console.ReadLine()):

```
    if (userSelection == "rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer Choice: Rock\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("Game [{0}] is a tie", game);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: "int computerSelection = r.Next(1,3)" in this sentence use (1,4) you will have a better result.

Comment: that helped a lot. Thank you very much